# pymata arduino with hc-sr04 TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, arduino

I am using arduino uno with the ultra sonic sensor and pyhon(pymata).I am on manjaro altough this might not be usefull.I am trying to make it detect the distance,but when I run it the following error appears TypeError: 'module' object is not callable.
The code I used is:

```
from random import triangular

from tkinter import OFF, ON

import speech_recognition as sr

from pyfirmata import Arduino

from pymata4 import pymata4

import time

#used to check if the arduino port selected is the right one
#board = Arduino('/dev/ttyACM0')
#print(board.get_firmata_version())
#led = board.get_pin('d:10:o')
#red = 9
#blue = 8
#yellow = 5
trig = 10
eco = 11


board = pymata4.Pymata4()

board = pymata4(com_port='/dev/ttyACM0')
board = pymata4(arduino_wait=10)


def the_callback(data):
    print("Distance is: ", data[2])

board.set_pin_mode_sonar(trig, eco, the_callback)

while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
        board.sonar_read(trig)
except Exception:
    board.shutdown()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines are wrong:

```
board = pymata4.Pymata4()

board = pymata4(com_port='/dev/ttyACM0')
board = pymata4(arduino_wait=10)
```

pymata4 is a module hence the error.

When you initialise `board` use the following syntax:

```
board = pymata4.Pymata4( com_port='/dev/ttyACM0', arduino_wait=10)
```